# AbsoluteLayout lost in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, absolutelayout

I made a Java application with AbsoluteLayout using NetBeans on a Machine then I moved project data files to another machine, there I got Reference Problem message for some libraries including AbsoluteLayout library.
I fixed project libraries and removed AbsoluteLayout.jar from Project libaries and added it again using Netbeans's add library option.
Now in the `Set Layout` menu there is no `AbsoluteLayout` !! (For all projects!!)

How Can I add AbsoluteLayout to SetLayout menu of Netbeans again?

Thanks

Comment: "*I made a Java application with AbsoluteLayout.."*  That's the problem.  ..What was the question?  (Not the down-voter.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: The question is how to get AbsoluteLayout back in NetBeans!

Comment: It sounds like you use the "Edit" button in the project libraries and then "Remove" (instead of just removing it). Radical solution: backing up your `.netbeans` folder and deleting it so that NB can recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radical solution that solves many Netbeans problems (specially those related to the user configuration) is removing the user directory and letting Netbeans recreate it.

Before NB 7.2 this folder was located inside the HOME user directory (`/home/user` or `C:\Users\user`)

Answer (score 1):

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020059/absolutelayout-lost-in-netbeans#comment17674305_13020059) by @madth3, this is easy to do. `AbsoluteLayout` is the first entry in the `Library` dialog, where its classpath can become the target of a hurried click on <kbd>Remove</kbd>.

As an alternative to this more [radical solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13035377/230513), navigate to the library configuration directory.

```
cd config/org-netbeans-api-project-libraries/Libraries
```

There should be a recent file named `absolutelayout.xml` containing the altered configuration.

```
$ ls
absolutelayout.xml
```

Remove the errant file and NetBeans will restore the original classpath on restart.

```
rm absolutelayout.xml
```

For reference, the full path to the original on Mac OS X, NetBeans 8 is

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 8.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/config/Modules/org-jdesktop-layout.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as netbeans not allowing me to add in build AbsoluteLayout library. As an alternate solution I searched for this jar file and found it under the netbeans installation directory. In my case it was under following path-

C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\modules\ext

from here I put it into my lib structure and everything worked fine, hope this post can help others. Happy Coding!!!